# Flashing Freescale K64F Board with mbed bin file end up with fail.txt containing "INVALID BINARY NVIC"

Tags: arm, iot, mbed

I try to flash the IBM InternetOfThingsKit Freescale K64F board with a binary compiled at mbed.org. I set the platform to "Ethernet IoT Starter Kit" and compiled the hello-world blinking LED example without any compiler errors.

After I copied the bin file on the mbed flash drive I instantly found the fail.txt file on the flashdrive. Even before pressing the button to flash the binary. The failed.txt file contains "INVALID BINARY NVIC".

I also tried it with "FRDM-K64F" instead of "InternetOfThingsKit" platform.

Comment: Seems to be a mac problem. Exactly the same with Linux worked without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MAC related problem. Starting with Yosemite MAC has a problem to mount the device in the right way and end up with a scrambled bin file which is then rejected by the bootloader. I still have the problem with OSX 10.10.5. Solution is to use a Linux machine or Virtual Box with a Linux OS.

http://embedxcode.weebly.com/blog/mbed-on-mac-os-x-yosemite-bug-and-time-to-innocence